# How to mock redshift queries integration test in Python and Pytest

Tags: python, pytest, amazon-redshift

I have Python code that looks like this:

```
db = de_core.db.redshift.get_connection()
...
query = get_query(f"export_user_{user_component}").render()
result = util.execute_query(db, query, user_id=user_id)
```

And it actually executes sql. I want to write an integration test that tests this sql. The sql is Redshift flavored sql... so like postgresql but not really. What's the best way to test this? Moto doesn't seem to support this kind of test. Are there any libraries that support this kind of integration test where I can mock out the real redshift connection with one that behaves like it?

I want to be able to setup tables in the test, create records, have sql execute against this mock, and return results. Is there anything like this?

Answer (score 0):

In general, mocking a database requires the database engine to run somewhere to execute your SQL.

That is why things like [test-containers](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-python) or [embedded-postgres](https://github.com/zonkyio/embedded-postgres) exist. Traditional apps would use these for their integration testing.

But as you noted Redshift is Posgtres-flavored, so if your code is Redshift-specific, then you might actually need Redshift to run your tests, with a test-dedicated database.

Some inspiration to create a wrapper class: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/123143/unit-tests-for-a-redshift-wrapper-class